# Aws CLI installation error on windows system

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

when i tried to install aws cli on cmd(Windows).  i am getting  message  first later its continued.you can see  below
[image]

By the way I added path in environmental variable like that
[image]

after finish intallation  i get this message
[image]

but still i am getting this message .what should i do please help me .
[image]

aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: can you check if the aws command exists inside the scripts directory

Comment: try the where command in the terminal. `where aws`

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>where aws
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: I have to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

see the error message during the installation, "Defauling to user installation because normal site-packages is not writable". So it has been installed inside your user directory.

to find out the user installatiion directory.

- you can open a python prompt by entering the command `python` in the command line
- import sys package `import sys`
- check the output of `sys.path`
- then you can add the script directoy of the python path to the `PATH` environment variable

Usually the installation location should be `c:\users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\scripts/aws.exe`

your python version might be different.

You should also add `c:\users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\scripts` to your path.

**update:** you can also use `pip show awscli` to see where the module is installed

Comment: Thank you  so much great job .I appreciate you